# recuperar data do bash ubuntu

Tags: bash

Estou montando um scrip para fazer o dump de um servidor Mysql, o nome do arquivo gerado é assim (bckp_all_13-09-2018.tar.bz2), porém eu queria armazenar a hora também, dessa forma (bckp_all_13-09-2018_14:44:22.tar.bz2).

Alguem sabe como fazer isso?

Exemplo do Código:

```
    #!/bin/bash
MY_USER="root"
MY_PASSWORD="123456"
MY_HOME="/home/hugo"
case $1 in
"backupall")
    cd $MY_HOME/Backup
    mysqldump --opt --password=$MY_PASSWORD --user=$MY_USER  --all-databases > bckp_all_$(date +'%d-%m-%Y').sql
    tar -cvjf bckp_all_$(date +'%d-%m-%Y').tar.bz2 bckp_all_$(date +'%d-%m-%Y').sql
    rm bckp_all_$(date +'%d-%m-%Y').sql;;
*)  echo "Others";;
esac
```

Comment: `'%d-%m-%Y'` define o formato de saída, então basta adicionar os parâmetros de horas, minutos e segundos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Da mesma forma que usou `%d-%m-%Y`, basta usar `%H-%M-%S`

Solução geral no Bash, se quiser guardar em variável em vez de repetir o comando 3x:

```
BKP_NAME=$(date -u +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S_UTC)
```

Horário local:

```
BKP_NAME=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S_%z)
```

- Note que `%d` `%m` `%Y` é péssimo para ordenação, o ideal é o mais significante primeiro.
- Evite os `:`, eles tem significado especial em caminho de arquivo. Se quer mesmo usar separadores, usar `14h30m18` é razoável para horas.
- Recomendo usar o `-u`, para evitar confusão com horário de verão (e como no exemplo, anotar que é UTC no nome do arquivo). Assim ficará com horário universal (pode até usar o local, tirando o -u, mas vai ter que tomar cuidado com horário de verão e portabilidade do script para outras máquinas). No caso do exemplo local acima, usei o `%z` no final, para acrescentar o fuso.

Para conhecer outros parâmetros, consulte o `man date` via linha de comando ou online:

> https://linux.die.net/man/1/date

Comment: Deu certo, porém o horário esta errado. Não esta no fuso de sao paulo.

Comment: -u é UTC, justamente pra evitar problema de fuso (se usar fuso, vai precisar anotar mais um parâmetro, o offset, senão horário de verão vai fazer uma bagunça). Mas se quer são paulo, só tirar o -u e configurar o servidor certinho.

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado pela sua ajuda.

Comment: @HugoBorges editei com um exemplo com fuso horário no final. Ex: 2017-12-20_13-49-12_-0300 (-0300 é o fuso de Brasilia em horario normal, em horario de verão vai ficar -0200)